# System services not available to Activities before onCreate(), with Android RecyclerView inside a fragment Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm having trouble with Android RecyclerView in Kotlin inside a fragment who is in Home activity.
Here's my code:

myFragmentLayout:

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvChapterList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

myFragmentCode:

```
    val chaptersList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    private lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.courses_layout, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        chaptersList.add("Android")
        chaptersList.add("Kotlin")
        chaptersList.add("RecyclerView")
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rvChapterList.layoutManager = layoutManager
        rvChapterList.adapter = ChapterAdapter(Home(), chaptersList)
     }
```

and myChapterAdapter:

```
class ChapterAdapter(private val context: Home, private val chaptersList: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ChapterAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return chaptersList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.chapterName?.text = chaptersList.get(position)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, chaptersList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val chapterName = view.tvChapterName
    }
}
```

It got this code from [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-recyclerview-in-kotlin) tutorial, it's working inside an activity but not iside a fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rvChapterList.adapter = ChapterAdapter(Home(), chaptersList)
```

Never create an `Activity` or other type of `Context` yourself. You always obtain them from the framework.

Replace that with:

```
rvChapterList.adapter = ChapterAdapter(requireActivity(), chaptersList)
```

and change the `context` property in `ChapterAdapter` to be a `Context` or `Activity`, not `Home`.